# Adding subject line for sending an email in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

Applying for a job need to send an email with some of the details like name,phonenumber,email,current ctc etcc..Email is sending correctly but the problem is while sending an email in subject line i need to include name email ctc...for this i have done this but it is not accepting in this format.

```
        $name = $this->input->post('fullname');
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $phone = $this->input->post('mobilenumber');
        $currentemploymentstatus = $this->input->post('current_employment_status');

        //set to_email id to which you want to receive mails
        $to_email = 'yyyy@gmail.com';

        $config=Array(
        'protocol'=> 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com', //smtp host name
        'smtp_port' => '465', //smtp port number
        'smtp_user' => 'xxxxxx@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'PASSWORD123', //$from_email password
        'mailtype' =>'html',
        'newline'  =>"\r\n",
        'crlf' =>"\r\n",
        'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
        'wordwrap' => TRUE
        );

        $message            = array();    
        $message[] = 'Fullname  :  '.trim($name).' ';
        $message[] = 'Email :  '.trim($email).' ';
        $message[] = 'Mobile :  '.trim($phone).' ';
        $message[] = 'Current Employment Status :  '.trim($currentemploymentstatus).' ';        

        //$message = implode(PHP_EOL, $message);
        $message = implode('<br>', $message);
        //send mail
        $this->load->library('email',$config);
        $this->email->from($email);
        $this->email->to($to_email);
        //$list = array();
        $this->email->subject($name|$email);
        $this->email->message($message);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->set_mailtype("html"); 
            if ($this->email->send())
        {
           $this->flash->success('Thank you for applying to this post we will get back to you soon!</div>');
            redirect('apply');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->flash->success('There is error in sending mail! Please try again later');
            redirect('apply');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Subject should be like this $name | $email

Comment: Try with this ..
$this->email->subject($name."|".$email);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Solved by adding this code.

```
$subject = $name .' | '.$currentemploymentstatus .' | '.$expectedctc .' | '.$primaryskills; 
        $this->email->subject($subject);
```

Answer (score 0):

For your problem try changing "|" to .'|'

To clean up your code and to make your life easier:

If you are using CI, check out my repository on setting up an email_model to simplify the code you are using. Instead of loading the config stuff for the library all you will need to do is hit the model to send to email queue and hit the model a second time to process the queue

https://github.com/ddell003/Email_model